# CSS: How to achieve - Two elements to be centered and positioned side by side WITHOUT a third parent container?

Tags: css, html, center, frontend

Problem: In the following HTML-markup:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="div_1"></div>
    <div id="div_2"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want both `div`'s (this can be any other tag) to be centered AND positioned side-by-side. How to achieve this with CSS, without adding a third parent container?

Comment: So you've solved this? Your answer below appears to work at first glance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Shehi/6RqWb/

Following CSS rules solve the problem:

```
#div_1
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -200px; /* = -1 * the width of element */
    float: left;
    clear: none;
}

#div_2
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    right: 50%;
    margin-right: -200px; /* = -1 * the width of element */
    float: right;
    clear: none;
}
```

Comment: +1, but I'm curious about the clear:none;  Could you give an explanation?

Comment: Lol... I just copied from my own code, so forgot to remove the `clear: none;` part from the answer... Sorry for that :) However, adding `clear: left` and `clear: right` to those elements would make sure they are the only ones in the row.